# Find formula for this sequence of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anybody know how to compute the cell (i,j) of this table, using just i and j?

In practice, given a cell (i,j): 
- the left-top number is computing summing the top row of cell (i,j-1)
- the right-top number is computing summing the bottom row of cell (i,j-1)
- the left-bottom number is computing summing the left column of cell (i-1,j)
- the right-bottom number is computing summing the right column of cell (i-1,j)

This said, I want a formula based on i and j that allows me to compute a cell, without having to compute the whole table.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The top row in cell $i=1,j=3$ does not obey either of the first two stated rules. it looks like the top right number is actually the sum of the *top* row of cell $(i,j-1)$. It looks like the top left number is the sum of the left column of numbers (or *bottom* row of numbers) in cell $(i,j-1)$. The top left number of cell $(4,4)$ is an **exception** to this rule. My guess is that the top row of cell $(4,4)$ should be $20\:15$. What are the rules exactly, and is the table correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your table does not agree with your rules. Let $c(i,j)$ be the entry in cell $\langle i,j\rangle$, considered as a $2\times 2$ matrix; then your table is constructed according to the rule $c(i,j)=c(i-1,j)+c(i,j-1)$, with initial conditions

$$c(1,j)=\begin{pmatrix}1&j-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{and}\qquad c(i,1)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\i-1&1\end{pmatrix}\;.$$

Assuming that the table is right, so that this is what you actually want, the general formula is

$$c(i,j)=\begin{pmatrix}\binom{i+j-2}{j-1}&\binom{i+j-2}{j-2}\\\binom{i+j-2}{j}&\binom{i+j-2}{j-1}\end{pmatrix}\;.$$

(Note that $\binom{n}k=0$ if $k<0$.) This is easily verified by induction on $i+j$. Suppose that it holds true for $i+j<k$, and let $m+n=k$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
c(m,n)&=c(m-1,n)+c(m,n-1)\\\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\binom{m+n-3}{n-1}+\binom{m+n-3}{n-2}&\binom{m+n-3}{n-2}+\binom{m+n-3}{n-3}\\\binom{m+n-3}{n}+\binom{m+n-3}{n-1}&\binom{m+n-3}{n-1}+\binom{m+n-3}{n-2}\end{pmatrix}\\\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}&\binom{m+n-2}{n-2}\\\binom{m+n-2}{n}&\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Have a closer look at the rules as these don't agree with the top rows of the cells in the table and cell $(4,4)$ may not be correct. Also, strictly speaking since all four rules are inductive you need a base case - this is the content of cell $(1,1)$.

The first thing you will notice, if you are familiar with Pascal's triangle, is that the numbers in any row of a cell are consecutive numbers somwhere in Pascal's triangle. Writing an "extended" form of Pascal's triangle that is zero-padded for numbers outside the usual triangle we get something like:

$$\begin{matrix}
 1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  2 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  3 &  3 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  4 &  6 &  4 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  5 & 10 & 10 &  5 &  1 &  0 &  0 & \ldots \\
 1 &  6 & 15 & 20 & 15 &  6 &  1 &  0 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{matrix}$$

where the rows and columns are numbered starting at $0$.

In the top row of cell $i,j=1$ in your table, you have the $1, 0$ elements starting on the diagonal of the $(i-2)-th$ row in Pascal's triangle.
To relate the top row of cells in your table to Pascal's triangle (PT), observe that:

- moving down a column in your table equates to moving down the diagonal in PT
- moving along a row in your table equates to moving down a column in PT

So then for the top left cell in row $i$, column $j$ in your table:

$$t_{i,j} = p_{i+j-2,j-1} = \binom{i+j-2}{j-1}$$

You will get the same formulae as given by Brian Scott in his answer.